# How to prepare a CSV HIT file containing Emoji character for Amazon Mechanical Turk

Tags: csv, emoji, mechanicalturk

Amazon's Mechanical Turk rejects CSV HIT files that contain 4-byte UTF-8 characters - such as Emoji. However, Emoji characters are an integral part of the worker tasks and I need to keep them.

I found the script at https://github.com/charman/mturk-emoji, which replaces the Emoji character with their equivalent HTML spans (e.g., ). However, when feeding the preprocessed CSV to MTurk, the Emoji characters are not rendered.

Comment: A minimal research showed: [Python + JavaScript workaround for mturk's rejection of CSV files with Emoji.](https://github.com/charman/mturk-emoji).   Can you show an example of the CSV you created? and the exact message that is returned when this is rejected?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I posted a working solution below. The key step is to add the proper Javascript code in the Mturk HTLM editor, otherwise, the emoji bytes produced by the Python scripts are not rendered in the Mturk preview.

Comment: Please do not forget to [accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/)  

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem following these steps.

1. Convert the CVS with UTF-8 Emojis using the script `encode_emoji.py` in the linked [GitHub repo](https://github.com/charman/mturk-emoji). You get, say, `sample_with_emoji.csv`.
2. In Mechanical Turk, edit your current project and go to `Design Layout`. In order for the HTML `span` with the emoji bytes to be properly rendered, you need to add the following code at the beginning in the HTML Editor of MTurk:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"
            integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60="
            crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
    function displayEmoji() {

  /**
   * utf8ByteArrayToString() copied from:
   *   https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/e877b1eac410c0d842bcda118689759512e0e26f/closure/goog/crypt/crypt.js
   *
   * Converts a UTF-8 byte array to JavaScript's 16-bit Unicode.
   * @param {Uint8Array|Array<number>} bytes UTF-8 byte array.
   * @return {string} 16-bit Unicode string.
   */
  var utf8ByteArrayToString = function(bytes) {
    var out = [], pos = 0, c = 0;
    while (pos < bytes.length) {
      var c1 = bytes[pos++];
      if (c1 < 128) {
        out[c++] = String.fromCharCode(c1);
      } else if (c1 > 191 && c1 < 224) {
        var c2 = bytes[pos++];
        out[c++] = String.fromCharCode((c1 & 31) << 6 | c2 & 63);
      } else if (c1 > 239 && c1 < 365) {
        // Surrogate Pair
        var c2 = bytes[pos++];
        var c3 = bytes[pos++];
        var c4 = bytes[pos++];
        var u = ((c1 & 7) << 18 | (c2 & 63) << 12 | (c3 & 63) << 6 | c4 & 63) -
                0x10000;
        out[c++] = String.fromCharCode(0xD800 + (u >> 10));
        out[c++] = String.fromCharCode(0xDC00 + (u & 1023));
      } else {
        var c2 = bytes[pos++];
        var c3 = bytes[pos++];
        out[c++] =
          String.fromCharCode((c1 & 15) << 12 | (c2 & 63) << 6 | c3 & 63);
      }
    }
    return out.join('');
  }

  jQuery(this).text(utf8ByteArrayToString(JSON.parse(jQuery(this).attr('data-emoji-bytes'))));
}
</script>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
      jQuery('span.emoji-bytes').each(displayEmoji);
    });
</script>
```

The above is basically the content at the bottom of the README file in the repo, with the script `decode_emoji.js` added inline rather than sourced.

3. Press save and you're good to go. Now, if you upload the `sample_with_emoji.csv` file, the emojis are properly rendered in the Preview.